# Determine Distance from a Fixed Point using Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have a simple Geolocation function which shows the user where they are on a Google Map. I'd like to add a function which tells the user how far away they are from a specific point, for instance, how far the user is away from The Whitehouse.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this page gives you several method, [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  since you may want to cover long distance (your user aren't in DC, correct?) you have to choose appropriate method, i'd guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Javascript implementation of the Haversine formula.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the latitude&longitude of the user, and you have the latitude&longitude of the fixed point, right? Just plug them into the [formula for great circle distance](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Unless you mean instead distance by transit lines or some other measure?